# worklight adapters and Groovy

Tags: groovy, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Has anyone had success implementing IBM Worklight 5.0.6 Adapters using the Groovy language? Ie. Instead of calling a Java class from the JS adapter call a Groovy class. We have tried this and it seems to work most of the time but randomly we will get strange errors when invoking an adapter procedure. Ie.

```
Failed to create DGM method proxy : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$24.<init>(java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass, java.lang.Class, [Ljava.lang.Class;)
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$24.<init>(java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass, java.lang.Class, [Ljava.lang.Class;)
```

Unit tests executing the Groovy code run fine within Eclipse and the Groovy code seems to be compiling fine down to .class files and included in the adapter package. We're wondering if this is an issue with Groovy itself or invoking Groovy within the Worklight server container. I believe Worklight is using Rhino behind the scenes which may also be a culprit?

We are using Groovy 2.1.5 and the Eclipse plugin 2.8

Answer (score 0):

did you open the .war and check if all compiled classes and libraries are actually in there? 
We had the case quite often that the WL Eclipse Plugin/Build did not compile and package our Java Classes for the Adapter in the "server" folder ... they were missing in the .war file that we deployed and we got all sorts of Rhino, ClassNotFound etc. errors.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer. You can always force a rebuild by selecting the project in the Enterprise Explorer or Navigator views, then select menu Project -> Clean -> Clean Projects Selected Below (the only choice should be your project).

This will clean the binaries, then rebuild your entire project.